How to rebase to initial revision minus 1 with git
I have five revisions in total and the first commit hash is 123. I want to squash all commits into one. If I do git rebase -i 123 I will end with a minimum of two commits. Any way to specify a virtual revision -1?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+first+commit

"How do I git rebase the first commit" is not a title I understand. Is this correct git language? However, the responses under that title do indeed answer my question.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+the+current+commit+the+only

@phd, I do understand "first commit" perfectly. It's the title I dont get and I am surprised "that people understand" it. But maybe it's just me.

You could try with git rebase -i --root  but if you mean to squash everything into the first commit, you could do this instead to avoid the rebase hassle:
git reset --soft 123
git commit --amend -m "Putting everything into a single commit"

As another way to do it, you could pull it off creating an orphan branch.

@BertF there is no need to do any previous steps.... Just the reset soft is enough.... It can be done when you have 5, 2 or 50 commits, it doesn't matter.

My mistake on the edit @eftshift0 - I got paranoid they were going to lose some edits because I confused --hard and --soft and didn't think it through completely. I should have just left a comment about my concern.

I'll add for the OP - after you do this (or any other method for collapsing the commits into 1 commit) and before you force push, you can do a git diff between your new 1-commit local branch and the multi-commit remote tracking branch to convince yourself that the end result is identical.
